# Почему коммиты Git не загружаются в удаленный репозиторий?

Tags: git, gitlab

Создал локальный клон удаленного репозитория на Git Lab. Пытаюсь сделать коммит в локальной версии и отправить его в удаленный репозиторий (на сервере Git Lab). Использую при этом клиент Git Gui. Клиент коммит отправляет, но когда заходишь в интерфейс Git Lab, то там внесенные изменения не отражаются.

Проверил подключение локальной папки к удаленной. При команде в консоли $ git remote -v, и на запись, и на скачивание показываются те же url, которые в удаленном репозитории показываются с кнопкой Clone, то есть, я так понимаю, подключение работает. А почему тогда изменения в локальном репозитории не влияют на удаленный?

на git push отвечает:

> remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project. fatal: unable to access 'такой-то': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: git push пробовали писать? какой ответ на эту команду?

Comment: на git push отвечает:
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'такой-то': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Ну вот и разгадка - у вас нет прав на пуш.

Comment: То есть администратор проекта мне их не дал? Или это может быть что-то другое.. связанное с тем, что мне их дали, но я что-то не так сделал..?

Comment: Да, скорее всего именно так. еще есть некоторая вероятность, что вы пытаетесь запушить в мастер, а у вас права только на другие ветки. но судя по ошибке скорее всего у вас вообще нет прав

Comment: или еще один вариант - у вас неправильно в настройках гита забито имя пользователя и пароль от гитлаба. например, у вас там почта и пароль от вашего гитхаба, а вы с ними пытаетесь в гитлаб пушить

Comment: Простите, что досаждаю, а может это быть связано, что я пытаюсь записать через https, а не SSH?

Comment: я бы начал всё же с проверки кредов - git config -l

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь..

Comment: Оказалось, с доступами проблема..